# How to add a space to only one line

Tags: java

I have been trying to make a calendar and have this coded so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class MyOwnCalendar {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


        System.out.print("Enter the number of days in month: ");
        int days = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.print("Enter which day the first day is on: ");
        int firstDay = keyboard.nextInt();

        System.out.println("S   M   T   W   Th  F   Sa");

        int ctr = 1;

        if (days == 31 && firstDay == 1)
        {
            while (ctr <= days)
            {
                System.out.print(ctr);
                System.out.print("  ");
                ctr++;
                if (ctr == 8 || ctr == 15 || ctr == 22 || ctr == 29)
                {
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }else if (days == 31 && firstDay == 2)
        {
            while (ctr <= days)
            {
                System.out.print("\t");
                System.out.print(ctr);
                System.out.print("  ");
                ctr++;
                if (ctr == 7 || ctr == 14 || ctr == 21 || ctr == 28)
                {
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        }
```

Everything was going well until here. If I enter 31 for `days`, and 2 for `firstDay`, this is the output:

```
Enter the number of days in month: 31
Enter which day the first day is on: 2
S   M   T   W   Th  F   Sa
    1   2   3   4   5   6  
    7   8   9   10  11  12  13              
    14  15  16  17  18  19  20  
    21  22  23  24  25  26  27  
    28  29  30  31
```

While the output for 31 `days`, and 1 for `firstDay`:

```
Enter the number of days in month: 31
Enter which day the first day is on: 1
S   M   T   W   Th  F   Sa
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   
8   9   10  11  12  13  14  
15  16  17  18  19  20  21  
22  23  24  25  26  27  28  
29  30  31
```

How would I indent only the first line for something like the first calendar I inputted? Also, if there is a more efficient way to code a calendar, instead of doing it like this, I would also greatly appreciate that. I am quite new to programming. I've only been learning for a couple weeks or so.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop is what loops through every line, so just move your new line to only happen for the first time through the loop. (Move `System.out.print("t");` above the `while` loop)

```
if (days == 31 && firstDay == 2)
{
    System.out.print("\t");
    while (ctr <= days)
    {
```

Comment: Do you know any shorter ways to do this though?

Comment: There are other ways to do it, but I don't think they would be any shorter or easier for the goal of printing out the days like you do. Looking at the [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) java class might be interesting for you if you plan on adding a lot more to it though.

Comment: You could change the `if (ctr == 8 || ctr == 15 || ctr == 22 || ctr == 29)` to `if (ctr + firstDay > 7)` which would make both your while loops the same, allowing you to only have one while loop if you rearrange a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

import java.util.*;
public class MyOwnCalendar {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);


    System.out.print("Enter the number of days in month: ");
    int days = keyboard.nextInt();

    System.out.print("Enter which day the first day is on: ");
    int firstDay = keyboard.nextInt();

   System.out.printf("%4c%4c%4c%4c%4c%4c%4c%n",'S','M','T','W','T','F','S');

    int ctr = 1;

    if (days == 31 && firstDay == 1)
    {
        while (ctr <= days)
        {
            System.out.printf("%4d",ctr);
           // System.out.print("  ");
             ctr++;
            if (ctr == 8 || ctr == 15 || ctr == 22 || ctr == 29)
            {
                System.out.println();
            }

        }
    }else if (days == 31 && firstDay == 2)
    {
        while (ctr <= days)
        {
            //System.out.print("\t");
            System.out.printf("%4d",ctr);
            //System.out.print("  ");

            if (ctr == 7 || ctr == 14 || ctr == 21 || ctr == 28)
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
              ctr++;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It better to use printf because it gives you better way of indenting the text :) and looks more organized :)

Comment: As said, I am a little new to programming, so what is printf? How would I use printf? When would I use printf instead of print?

Comment: It formats the text based on the format specification. Here is the link bellow.... everything about printf is here http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/java/java_formatted_strings.html

Comment: One more piece information, increment ctr after the if statement in the second while loop.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think there are better, easier ways to do something like this though?

Comment: Sorry to say but as far you are learning programming don't take easy steps into consideration instead should be concern about minimizing the   redundancy and improving the efficiency of the code. The best advice would practicing  and mess around with the code,it will teach you a lot :).